# How Assigning selected text of dropdown in textbox of GridView in Asp.net

Tags: jquery, asp.net, gridview, selected

if you want to assign selected text value of dropdown list to textbox that is present in another cell of the same row. You can use jQuery to achieve the same. Kindly refer the below example for the same.

```
$(function() {  
$("[id*=ddlCurrency]").change(function() {  
var ddy = $(this).find('option').filter(':selected').text();  
var row = $(this).closest("tr");  
 $("[id*=txtProjectCurrencyName]", row).val(ddy);  
});
```

});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is working unless you have script error in other places.

Here is my testing -

[image]

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="GridViewDemo.aspx.cs" Inherits="DemoWebForm.GridViewDemo" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <asp:GridView runat="server" ID="GridView1" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Id" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" />
                <asp:TemplateField>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="ddlCurrency">
                            <asp:ListItem Text="" Value="" />
                            <asp:ListItem Text="USD" Value="USD" />
                            <asp:ListItem Text="EUR" Value="EUR" />
                            <asp:ListItem Text="GBP" Value="GBP" />
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtProjectCurrencyName" />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(function () {
                $("[id*=ddlCurrency]").change(function () {
                    var ddy = $(this).find('option').filter(':selected').text();
                    var row = $(this).closest("tr");
                    $("[id*=txtProjectCurrencyName]", row).val(ddy);
                });
            });
        </script>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

### Code Behind

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace DemoWebForm
{
    public partial class GridViewDemo : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        public class Currency
        {
            public int Id { get; set; }
            public string Name { get; set; }
        }

        public static IList<Currency> Currencies = new List<Currency>
        {
            new Currency {Id = 1, Name = "One"},
            new Currency {Id = 2, Name = "Two"},
            new Currency {Id = 3, Name = "Three"}
        };

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                GridView1.DataSource = Currencies;
                GridView1.DataBind();
            }
        }
    }
}
```